# vuetify error SassError: Expected identifier

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I just started a new Vue project with Vuetify, but when i add a component such as (datatable,carousel) i get this error: "

**THIS ERROR IS FOR ADDING V-DATABLE**

```
   Syntax Error: SassError: Expected identifier.
      ╷
   68 │       position: relative
      │                         ^
      ╵
  node_modules\vuetify\src\components\VSelect\VSelect.sass 68:25  root stylesheet
```

**THIS ERROR IS FOR ADDING V-CAROUSEL**

```
 Syntax Error: SassError: Expected identifier.
  ╷
4 │   overflow: hidden
  │                   ^
  ╵
```

node_modules\vuetify\src\components\VWindow\VWindow.sass 4:19  root stylesheet

I think it's a bug any help on how to fix it

Comment: 2 ways I think, open a pull request and wait until merged or downgrade vuetify version to a lower.

Comment: Can you please add which version you hab when the bug was happening?

Answer (score 6):

it was a bug and this is the fix

```
   npm install sass@1.32.8
```

Comment: thank you! saved me a bunch of time, just in time. :)

Comment: This bug seems to be re-introduced/originate in 1.32.9/10. Downgrade to 1.32.8 solved this for me.

Comment: Downgrade to 1.32.8 solved this for me too, thanks!